# MVP, design question

Tags: design-patterns, mvp

I working on a MVP designed application and have some design questions.
When writing code in the presenter-layer how should the communication go between different presenters/views?
Lets say I have a WindowPresenter with its WindowView and I want to set the window title on a window from another window. I have a title-setter on the window view that wraps the actual gui title. Should I call the title-setter directly on the view (windowPresenter.View.Title = "Title") or should I wrap the view title as a presenter title setter (windowPresenter.Title = "Title") ?

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself how would you test it? If you do windowPresenter.View.Title = "Title", how can you test that presenter is setting the title?

Comment: Ah thank you, I felt there was something that didn't fit. Maybe its even a bad design decision to expose the presenters view?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice article that focuses quite a lot on similar things in MSDN magazine this month:

[Beyond MVP - Extending the MVP Pattern for Enterprise-Class Application UI Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336019.aspx)